# highchart with angular and ionic framework error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, highcharts

I want to make a graph on my web app.

I don't understand how angular with highcharts works.

I use this lib : github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
and this framework : ionicframework.com/

I think it can be the same with apache cordova.

I made a simple page with :

```
<highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>
```

then, on my app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ui.router', 'highcharts-ng']);
```

then on my controller js page :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Dashboard',....) 
{
    $scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },

        loading: false
    };

}
```

and of course : no graph, an error on the js console :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Xa.init (http://localhost:63342/www/js/highcharts.js:190:242)
    at Object.Xa (http://localhost:63342/www/js/highcharts.js:15:293)
    at link.m (http://localhost:63342/www/js/highcharts-ng.min.js:8:2964)
    at link (http://localhost:63342/www/js/highcharts-ng.min.js:8:3058)
    at http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15996:44
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15605:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15009:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15599:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15009:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15012:13) <div id="chart1" config="chartConfig">
```

My questions :

- If I put the dependency on

  ```
  angular.module('myApp', ['highcharts-ng']).controller('Dashboard',....)
  ```

blank page, so I assume that it's on app.js only.... right or wrong ?

- How to solve my problem ?

PS : To JSFiddle or CodePen user, here is your graal :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ateyI

Is not exactly my project but reproduce this problem.
Thanks !

Comment: At the beginning, attach a jquery, but next error is in te ionic.bundle.js 30705 line, so maybe update ionic framework.

Comment: @FrPolymer have you solved it ? ? ?

Answer (score 2):

Debug it using chrome's web inspector. For me, when i had the same error, the addEvent function was the culprit. Checking the definition made me realise that **I had forgotten to include jquery**. I suspect it's the same case for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included standalone-frameform.js?

```
<script src="lib/highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Vlad is right. You need to include standalone-framework.js.
Moreover, you don't need to load Angular, since the Ionic Bundle includes it.

So, the scripts are:

```
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.10/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/master/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
```

Here is a working version of your Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYrvvV

Comment: It needs to be clearer in highcharts documentation that you need both highcharts.js and standalone framework included

Comment: @zambono Note that it's the case only if you don't include jQuery in your page, as stated in the ["Installation" page of the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation) (option 2). It is true, though, that mentioning it in the README of highcharts-ng would be useful. I just submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/pull/271) :)